# React 16v - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bool' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-16

I updated my project's react version from 15.3.1 to 16.2.0. I'm getting the following runtime error message.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bool' of undefined
    at eval (Transition.js?0efa:259)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:4059)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:1337)
    at fn (bundle.js:744)
    at eval (398:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:3348)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:1337)
    at fn (bundle.js:744)
    at eval (99:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:1647)
```

I did the update gradually and the app worked well in 15.6.2. The error started appearing after I updated it to 16.0.0. I updated it to 16.2.0 hoping it would resolve it. But no luck. My webpack.config.js and package.json is below

**package.json**

```
{
    "name": "myProject",
    "version": "28.0.0",
    "description": "New front end",
    "main": "main.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "jest",
        "test-coverage": "jest --coverage",
        "dev": "webpack --config webpack.config.js -d --watch",
        "build": "webpack --config ./webpack.config.production.js --progress -p",
        "start": "webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack.config.js --hot"
    },
    "repository": "",
    "author": "Sarani",
    "license": "BSD",
    "dependencies": {
        "babel": "~6.5.2",
        "babel-core": "~6.13.2",
        "babel-loader": "~6.2.4",
        "babel-polyfill": "~6.16.0",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "~6.13.2",
        "babel-preset-react": "~6.11.1",
        "create-react-class": "^15.6.3",
        "css-loader": "~0.18.0",
        "file-loader": "~0.9.0",
        "isomorphic-fetch": "~2.2.1",
        "json-loader": "~0.5.4",
        "less": "~2.7.1",
        "less-loader": "~2.2.3",
        "moment-range": "~3.0.3",
        "moment-timezone": "~0.5.13",
        "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
        "react": "^16.0.0",
        "react-bootstrap": "~0.30.2",
        "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
        "react-redux": "~4.4.5",
        "react-router": "^3.2.0",
        "redux": "~3.5.2",
        "redux-immutable-state-invariant": "~1.2.3",
        "redux-thunk": "~2.1.0",
        "style-loader": "~0.13.1",
        "url-loader": "~0.5.7",
        "webpack": "^3.10.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-eslint": "~6.1.2",
        "babel-jest": "~14.1.0",
        "eslint": "~3.5.0",
        "eslint-config-airbnb": "~11.1.0",
        "eslint-loader": "~1.5.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "~1.15.0",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "~2.2.2",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "~6.2.2",
        "gulp": "~3.9.1",
        "gulp-csslint": "~1.0.0",
        "gulp-watch": "~4.3.10",
        "jest": "~14.1.0",
        "jest-cli": "~14.1.0",
        "react-a11y": "~0.3.3",
        "react-addons-test-utils": "~15.3.2",
        "react-test-renderer": "~15.3.1",
        "redux-mock-store": "~1.2.1",
        "webpack-dev-server": "~1.14.1"
    },
    "jest": {
        "automock": false,
        "moduleNameMapper": {
            "^.+\\.(css|less)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js",
            "^.+\\.(gif|ttf|eot|svg)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
            "^config$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/configMock.js"
        },
        "moduleFileExtensions": [
            "js",
            "jsx"
        ]
    }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'eval-source-map',
    entry: {
        bundle: ['babel-polyfill', './Main.js'],
        bundleIntegrated: ['babel-polyfill', './MainIntegrated.js']
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../assets/myProject'),
        filename: '../assets/myProject/[name].js'
    },
    target: 'web',
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        port: 8080,
        proxy: {
            '/myct/**': {
                target: 'http://localhost:9000',
                secure: false,
                changeOrigin: true
            }
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ],
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
        alias: {
            config: path.join(__dirname, 'config/config.dev')
        }
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
                {
                    test: /.(js|jsx)$/,
                    enforce: 'pre',
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: [
                            {
                                loader: "eslint-loader",
                            }
                        ],
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                    exclude: /(node_modules|__tests__)/,
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                },
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: [
                            "style-loader",
                            "css-loader",
                        ],
                },
                {
                    test: /\.less$/,
                    use: [
                            "style-loader",
                            "css-loader",
                            "less-loader",
                        ],
                },
                {
                    test: /\.woff($|\?)|\.woff2($|\?)|\.ttf($|\?)|\.eot($|\?)|\.svg($|\?)/,
                    use: [
                            {
                                loader: "file-loader?name=../assets/myProject/fonts/[name].[ext]",
                            },
                        ],
                },
        ]
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to fix this issue. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: @OrB I added the webpack.config.js and package.json. Let me know if that's enough.

Comment: I meant the actual piece of code that throws.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.

If you run `yarn info react-bootstrap peerDependencies`, you will see the following:

```
{
    react: '>=16.8.0',
    'react-dom': '>=16.8.0'
}
```

So, make sure the versions are correct.

I've fixed it by running `yarn add react@latest` and also `yarn add react-dom@latest`. In addition, I set `react-bootstrap` to `0.32.4`, as version `1.0.0` threw different errors.

```
"react": "^16.13.1",
"react-bootstrap": "0.32.4",
"react-dom": "^16.13.1",
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your help. I managed to fix the issue by updating the following to latest versions. The solution can be found [here](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/2883)

```
"react": "latest",
"react-dom": "latest",
"react-bootstrap": "latest",
"react-router-dom": "latest"
```